# How can I transfer half mining award to an address?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, consensus, address.transfer

Creating a dapp, which requires half allocated mining fee should go to an address.

I managed to cut down the mining as well as the block reward:

**consensus.go**

```
    // Accumulate the rewards for the miner and any included uncles
    reward := new(big.Int).Set(blockReward)
    rew := new(big.Int).Set(blockReward)
    r := new(big.Int)
    for _, uncle := range uncles {
        r.Add(uncle.Number, big8)
        r.Sub(r, header.Number)
        r.Mul(r, blockReward)
        r.Div(r, big8)
        state.AddBalance(uncle.Coinbase, r)

        r.Div(blockReward, big32)
        reward.Add(reward, r)
    }

    changedRew := new(big.Int).Set(rew) // half reward
    changedRew.Div(changedRew, big.NewInt(2))
    log.Warn("Mining block reward status .. ", "CHANGED", changedRew )
    state.AddBalance(header.Coinbase, changedRew)
}
```

**state_transition.go**

```
        if vmerr == vm.ErrInsufficientBalance {
            return nil, 0, false, vmerr
        }
    }
    st.refundGas()
    log.Warn("Half fee taken away ")
    // change price 
    st.state.AddBalance(st.evm.Coinbase, changedRew.Div(new(big.Int).Mul(new(big.Int).SetUint64(st.gasUsed()), st.gasPrice), big.NewInt(2)))

    return ret, st.gasUsed(), vmerr != nil, err
}
```

How can I now transfer the other half to an address? If I specify an account/address to be transferred , that can be easily changed without effecting the block rules. How can I do it securely ?

P.S : Just one account constant account for every node to transfer half mining fee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As easy as this:

```
the_other_half_addr:=common.HexToAddress("0xlajfklsadjflsafjklsadjdflkadjfl")
state.AddBalance(the_other_half_addr,changedRew)
```

You are doing it securely, but you forgot to take the half from the uncles too.

Comment: Thanks ! It's secure because if the address is changed, it will result into a different block hash. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, the Root() of the types.Block will return a different output since every modification to the State will change its hash . But you have to verify this in a test, just to be sure you didn't made any mistake. Create a 2 different `datadir`s and mine one block with different addresses. The hashes of the Root() and Hash() of the block should be different in both `datadir`s, If someone modifies this address and runs his own node, his block will be discarded by the network on the first block with different hash.

Comment: I tried doing it. Keeping keystore same for `datadir ` and `datadir2`, it gave me a different `stateRoot` hash .From the first `datadir`, I kept the same keystore and `minerBase`. Then I re-ran the setup from `datadir2`, which gave me same state hash each new time. Then I changed the account address from the source, the `stateRoot` hash was different this time.So it does verify it. But what could be the possible reason i was unable to get same state root same as `datadir` (original folder) ?

Comment: Also, the `transactions Root` are same in every case.Is this because i'm mining empty blocks? I think transactions have different tree than the state.